# Angular Template driven form dynamic form part

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I don't know what to google to find an answer to my question so I'm asking here.
I have to create a form with one part that is always the same, there are some input fields you can only fill once per form. And then there is a group of fields that I want to enable the user to create multiple instances of.
It would look something like this:
Field 1, Field 2, Button with 'Add field 3-5' and if you click it you can fill in the fields 3-5, afterwards you can either submit the form or add anoter instance of fields 3-5 and so on.
I'm completely new to forntend stuff so I don't know if there is a word for this.
Anyways I would appreciate your help.

Comment: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-fields-in-angularexample.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick tutorial, helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular's [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) and [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) will help you to achieve this easily.

you can define a `FormArray` like a `FormControl` when you create your `FormGroup` and loop through it in your UI.

```js
  demoForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  output =  {}

  get firstName(): FormControl {
    return this.demoForm.controls["firstName"] as FormControl;
  }
  get lastName(): FormControl {
    return this.demoForm.controls["lastName"] as FormControl;
  }
  get optionals(): FormArray {
    return this.demoForm.controls["optionals"] as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.demoForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstName: this._formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required]),
      lastName: this._formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required]),
      optionals: this._formBuilder.array([]),
  /*  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  */
    });
  }
```

and in your HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="demoForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" />

    <div formArrayName="optionals">
    <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
        <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let optionals of optionals.controls; index as i;">
        <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
            <input type="text" formControlName="attr1" />
            <input type="text" formControlName="attr2" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

you can add or remove items from the array with something like this :

```js
  AddOptionalItems(){
     // you can add validation here on each item individually.
     const group = new FormGroup({
      attr1: new FormControl(''),
      attr2: new FormControl(''),
    });
    this.optionals.push(group);
  }

  RemoveOptionalItems(i:number){
    this.optionals.removeAt(i);
  }
```

here is a small [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-dynamic-forms-demo?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with a more complete version.

EDIT :

a helpful article: https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot for your detailed description, it helped me a lot. First I was trying to use the template driven form, but this is much better.